# Enabling divi builder on wooCommerce Product Pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I purchased divi, it's a great 'drag and drop' builder  to build page layouts.

However, on wooCommerce product pages, the 'use divi builder' button is not there.

Does anyone know the internal workings of the plugin well enough to allow for the button to appear on the product pages.

I did contact their support, but they don't seem to want to answer harder questions.

[image: Divi builder enabled for posts]

[image: Divi builder not showing for wooCommerce products]

Comment: Have you tried contacting Divi support?

Comment: "I did contact their support, but they don't seem to want to answer harder questions"

Comment: While you maybe can't support every plugin ever, as one of the most popular ones, it's surprising that it doesn't support WooCommerce. I don't have Divi so I don't have any answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily integrate the Divi builder into Woocommerce or any other custom post type for that matter with a small code snippet which can be added to your Theme's functions file. Remember to use a child theme whenever customizing theme core files such as the functions.php file as we will be.

If you are not familiar with a WordPress Child Theme you can always use one of my prefered  plugins when in a crunch for time. [Child Theme Creator by Orbisius](https://wordpress.org/plugins/orbisius-child-theme-creator/)

Here is the snippet to add woocommerce to the child theme, I also added a second custom post type to further show you how this example works.

```
 // Begin Adding Divi Builder Support to Custom Post Type
 function my_et_builder_post_types( $post_types ) {
     $post_types[] = 'product'; // This is the name of the Woocommerce custom post type
     $post_types[] = 'latest_news'; // My own custom post type I have added to my website.

     return $post_types;
 }
 add_filter( 'et_builder_post_types', 'my_et_builder_post_types' );
 // End Adding Divi Builder Support to Course Post Type
```

So what have we done here?

1st. We created our function

2nd. We specified our post types we want added

3rd. We added our new filter

There you have it, its that simple. This will allow you to better layout your description content on your woocommerce product pages.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer is much down the timeline but I think it will be helpful for others who are trying to achieve the same thing.
This Elegant themes blog post describes a solution, the
[Divi Commerce Plugin](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/divi-plugin-highlight-divi-commerce)
and here is the link to [Bolt Themes](https://www.boltthemes.com/product/divi-commerce/)
Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

The Divi builder can't be activated on product pages. This feature is not supported.

This is with the Divi builder plugin and the Divi theme itself.

I personally feel that you will be using product / page functionality of you had Divi active on the single product pages.

From a user experience you will be loosing the direction to getting a client to add the product and checkout as the page will be out completely.

Use Divi for your main pages and marketing, keep the WooCommerce pages for the products!